# delphi freeze and activate order

Tags: delphi, vcl, pos

I am trying to make small POS system, using `FDMem` table to fill items for the customer.

In case the customer forget his money or go to change a product .. and the customers in the line move and new customer shows up asking to start sale process, how can I save or freeze the current state of the `FDMem` table holding the products of the previous customer and start a new order and finish the sale. Then, when the first customer comes back, how can I resume the previous sales process and reactivate the previous `FDMem` table with it's items?

Comment: The question is too vague at the moment to give any form of answer. Surely each customer has an individual id number and that number is stored in the table along with the order. So a second customer should have no effect on any tuple that doesn't have the (second) customer's id.

Comment: hello guys , i have been advised that i should not add a field to table  , and search for the onhold orders even if it is correct way . some says you need some thing like pagecontrol , and create a sheet for the new buyer ,with the same pos form inside it ,it is not easy to implement , and re do it if the case , occurs multiple time and just move from tab to tab to close sales, that is why i did not mark this answered yet..

Answer (score 1):

Add one more column in the FDMem table. That column could take 3 values: 'Finalized', 'Opened' and 'Paused' depending how the "status" of the sales is going. You can then navigate between the records.

Comment: That won't solve the problem. What if you have two or more people that needed to "Pause" their purchases due to some reason? In such case your solution will backfire as it will merge incomplete purchases of two or more people.

Comment: @SilverWarior If several people have the "paused" status then operator can simply continue to browse the result set of "... where paused" until he finds the correct customer which is in front of him. This is even a desirable behavior!

Comment: That would only work if OP already has needed field to store customer ID for each purchased item record.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to be able to handle multiple customers or orders at the same time.

One solution one would guess would be to assign each customer unique number and them add that number as additional field to each record in your database. Now assigning unique values to online customers isn't particularly difficult. In fact you already have such information in form of session ID. But doing something like this for customers in a physical store is not feasible.

But there is another similar solution. Most Tax authorities require any shops to issue a receipt for any purchase made. And each of those receipts needs to have a unique number. So you could reserve a new receipt number when customer gets to your POS for the first time and you start adding its items to the system. Then you might want to have another table with all reserved receipt numbers and their current status, so you can know which receipt has been finished which one is still pending completion or which one was cancelled.